# How to create dynamic size columns in C# .net 4.0 using TableLayout in WinForms

Tags: c#-4.0, layout

I want two rows and first row has two columns. But I do not found any property by which I can set size of column. I place toolbar in first row and first column. I want to hide it progemmatically. So, how to design UI by using TableLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ColumnStyles property:

```
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].Width = 0;
```

Not so sure that makes sense, every control in the colum will get hidden and the other columns will grow proportionally.  Hiding a control is otherwise simple, just set its Visible property to false.